# Is using a well know Singleton pattern to save state in a stateless MVC application considered a good approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, singleton

I need to save some session/user related information in my MVC project. Since it should be unique and available throughout the lifetime of the session, I thought about "session-wide" singleton. I found several posts on this subject (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134511/asp-net-singleton), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194999/are-static-class-instances-unique-to-a-request-or-a-server-in-asp-net) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806810/should-this-singleton-be-thread-safe-in-an-asp-net-app)) but then I remembered reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181629/why-session-is-a-disaster-in-asp-net-mvc-application) about not using the Session object in a MVC application. Since this sounds like a generally bad idea, I thought about using [the 4th version of Jon Skeet's singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx#cctor). In a couple of quick tests I wasn't able to see any violation of the singleton pattern per user session (i.e. only one object for every session was created). I might have missed something or might not have tested it correctly.

Is it safe to use this pattern for a session singleton in a MVC project (without saving the object in `HttpContext.Current.Session` or `HttpContext.Current.Items`)?

Comment: A singleton is not your solution, since a single object will be created, and that object will be used for all requests.

Comment: I would use either a database, or session. I don't see how the singleton can help in this case, unless the data you want to preserve is shared among users.

Comment: @Maarten, that's what I'm going for: a single (state) object that can be accessed from any request during the current session.

Comment: @AKhudairy, a singleton object could be used from any action that needs to "store" some data about the current execution. It would be used pretty much as a static object, but would not be available to the entire application, but to the current session.

Comment: @AndreiV am just not getting it. if you come up with a good implementation please share it :)